# NGINX API Gateway- Does NGINX forwards the to upstream servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gateway

I have a question that in a environment where NGINX is acting as a reverse proxy, then does NGINX forwards or creates a new HTTP request for the upstream server ?

And in case NGINX is configured to perform authentication also, then once the user is authenticated, then in future requests, how NGINX and upstream servers will know that the user is authenticated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NGINX forwards the request to upstream servers. It modifies two request headers and removes the empty request headers. When the request is forwarded the requested URL is placed in X-Target header. Refer to NGINX-Blog in NGINX.com.

Comment: Can u tell me about the authentication part of my question also